# AngularJS - attach same controller to multiple html elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-controller

I have a sample HTML like this where each div represent tons of html code.
I need to attach a piece of html code to a controller which is already attached to one div.
Both the first and last div represent the same business functionality and are tightly coupled and hence I cannot use services to share the state. 
I am looking for a solution other than using angular or ui routing.

```
<div ng-controller='newController'>
<label>{{greeting}}</label>
</div>

<div>
<!-- Another Big HTML element -->
</div>

<div>
<!-- This is some popup dialog code which should be attached to the scope of newController -->
<label>{{greeting}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3151330 heeey, if my answer work out for you, mark as accepted 8)

Answer (score 4):

You just have to attach ng-controller to the div's that you want, like this:

```
<div ng-controller='newController'>
    <label>{{greeting}}</label>
</div>

<div>
    <!-- Another Big HTML element -->
</div>

<div ng-controller='newController'>
    <!-- This is some popup dialog code which should be attached to the scope of newController -->
    <label>{{greeting}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it doesn't work. Whenever angular sees an ng-controller it instantiates a new controller object. Please see the plunker below. Click the buttons and you understand what I'm talking about.

http://plnkr.co/edit/o80j1iWaPmrEdGExCK09?p=preview

Comment: I think that It is due to the third div in your example is not refreshed by buttons http://plnkr.co/edit/o80j1iWaPmrEdGExCK09?p=preview. The buttons do the magic...